# UI modification of individual application (Phone,Contacts) in ICS AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I have already successfully modified few applications (Launcher,SMS,Gallery,Email,Calendar) of AOSP but I am facing problems to modify `Phone,Contacts` applications.

I have gone through the following steps to modify `Launcher,SMS,Gallery,Email,Calendar` applications:

1. I have downloaded ICS AOSP and imported individual application in eclipse.
2. I have changed the package names.i.e. `com.android.launcher2` to `com.test.launcher2`
3. After `Step 1` and `Step 2`,I was facing errors in individual application because of missing framework classes.I have solved them by importing those missing classes in my application.
4. I have modify UI of the my application.
5. I have run the application on emulator.and it's working fine.

Now, I am facing problem while modifying Contacts,Phone applications inside `Step 3`:

-> When I import missing framework classes of `java.*` or `javax.*` in my application,the Console informs me by the error like `Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library.`

-> To overcome the issues,I tried to include few jar libraries which were specified in `Android.mk` file and were generated while building downloaded AOSP (ICS).but it didn't solve my issue.

-> I guess `com.android.phone.common` jar file may solve the issue but I am not able to solve it as I suspect the classes are missing in that file which I got from build.So I am trying to find it on internet since few days,but I couldn't find it.so **if anybody have the full(working) version of this jar file,please share it**.

**NOTE:** My development machine has Windows 7.and my short term goal is to modify UI of the Contact,Phone applications and run it .

**EDIT:** Screenshots of Buildpath
[image]
[image]

**EDIT** After putting TimSort.java in default package,

[image]

I have described this step at github demo also by saying "when I import TimSort.java ,it tries to access some hidden method of Arrays.java class,So I need to import that class".this error is the reason why i created java.util package to include Arrays.java class.otherwise I am happy with importing just TimSort.java.by the way,in screenshot we can see the `comment` which says something specially about next 2 methods

Comment: Can you describe your 3rd step in detail so we can reproduce what you 've done? Especially how did you add those missing framework classes and what are they?

Comment: I found the missing classes from AOSP source by searching it by the name of missing class iteself.`i.e.` After Step 2 in `Calendar` application i was missing `AsYouTypeFormatter.java` class ,so I found it from downloaded AOSP and included it in my application inside the package name which was mentioned in that particular class which I found,and in this case package name was `com.android.i18n.phonenumbers`.so I created such package in my application and put that class inside it.Error solved.

Comment: @JermaineXu: Hi,can you give me any suggestions or wild guess to solve my issue?

Comment: Can you check whether your eclipse has passed rt.jar or android.jar to dx? I'll try to make an answer. If it doesn't work, I'll delete it.

Comment: @JermaineXu: Yes,It has been passed.

Comment: @JermaineXu: Hey man,sorry for misunderstanding created over here,I said "it has been passed" means `Eclipse` has passed `implicitly`.I haven't added them in build path of my application.and yeah as per your suggestion, I haven't changed `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shared"` of the manifest file.

Comment: So there is no jar named android.jar in your build path? I didn't mean you added it, sometimes eclipse will misplace it.

Comment: @JermaineXu: No, it is not there in build path.

Comment: What happened if you remove the coreApp="true" in AndroidManifest.xml? Clean and rebuild after removing it.

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of your build path?

Comment: @JermaineXu: there is no attribute like `android:coreApp=true` inside `<manifest>` tag as shown here `https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/AndroidManifest.xml?repo=platform--packages--apps--contacts&name=android-4.0.1_r1.2`.

Comment: @JermaineXu:BTW man,I'm still at `Step 3` as I have mentioned in my question.I need to solve errors of missing classes before moving further towards building/running application and for that I guess I need some libraries as stated here `https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/Android.mk?repo=platform--packages--apps--contacts&name=android-4.0.1_r1.2` and that is what I am in search of.

Comment: @JermaineXu: I have uploaded the screenshots in question itself.

Comment: Have no idea about what's going wrong. Since I failed to reproduce your error, can you upload your entire project and give us a download link so I can take some wild try on get over that error?

Comment: I think the main problem is you include the java.* and javax.*, which already exists in android.jar. So I think provide your entire project or the files(java.*, javax.*) you imported may help.

Comment: Ok.I will provide you link of my github repo after creating a small demo application of my issue.

Comment: @JermaineXu: kindly look at the demo app which I have uploaded on GitHub : `https://github.com/Joisar/Demo-App` . I have explained the whole issue step-by-step with screenshots.

Comment: Removed the java.util package in your project, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in the last comment, the main problem is you include the java.* and javax.*, which already exists in android.jar. So the builder thought you are building the core library while you are not.

I simply delete the java.util.* package in your project. And no errors. The android.jar has already included many packages including java.xxx and javax.xxx. If there really is a missing java core library you need to use, try refactoring.

[image: Eclipse Snapshot]

I checked the Android source, the dx will check the name of your source first by calling:

```
private static void checkClassName(String name) {
    boolean bogus = false;

    if (name.startsWith("java/")) {
        bogus = true;
    } else if (name.startsWith("javax/")) {
        int slashAt = name.indexOf('/', 6);
        if (slashAt == -1) {
            // Top-level javax classes are verboten.
            bogus = true;
        } else {
            String pkg = name.substring(6, slashAt);
            bogus = (Arrays.binarySearch(JAVAX_CORE, pkg) >= 0);
        }
    }

    if (! bogus) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * The user is probably trying to include an entire desktop
     * core library in a misguided attempt to get their application
     * working. Try to help them understand what's happening.
     */

    DxConsole.err.println("\ntrouble processing \"" + name + "\":\n\n" +
            IN_RE_CORE_CLASSES);
    errors++;
    throw new StopProcessing();
}
```

The `IN_RE_CORE_CLASSES` is the error string you see in the console. That explains why it shows that error.

UPDATE:

Screenshot after adding TimSort.java.

[image: Screenshot after adding TimSort.java]

Comment: In the demo project I have already described that I need to use many missing classes i.e. `TimSort.java` which are not included in android.jar .and while trying to use it by creating package,I'm facing issues due to existing classes i.e. `Arrays.java` . Insort,I know the problem,I am looking for solution.Just removing the java.* packages isn't solution because it contains missing classes too.

Comment: #PS: Inside `MainActivity.java` of the demo project,if you try to use TimSort's methods ,it will show error.because `TimSort` isn't included in android.jar

Comment: Yes, TimSort isn't included in android.jar, but Arrays.java is. To use TimSort, you don't need to create a package named "java.*" or "javax.*", just add to your existing package. Altogether, you need to avoid create any package named java.* or javax.*. Put anything you want to use into other packages and modify the "package java..." clause in the corresponding file. @MehulJoisar

Comment: By looking at your screenshot,m surprised,Have you commented any code inside TimSort.java? because I am having different scenario over here.kindly look at the update which I have added to my question.and yes,Thanks for your co-operation man :-)

Comment: I use the TimSort from [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java). And from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), there is no checkStartAndEnd method. @MehulJoisar

Comment: Ok,that is the difference.I am using TimSort from the downloaded ICS AOSP because ultimately I want to include the functionalities of ICS OS.and my TimSort is having such method as you can see in github demo project.anyways I am thankful to your efforts and the time which you have contributed.I have upvoted :-)

Comment: Anyway, I'll try to figure out why this is not included in sdk, but generally it is not difficult to fix this error after understanding you cannot create any java.* or javax.* package in your source. For example, when you copy the TimSort.java, you can put it into another package and copy the implementation of checkStartAndEnd as a static method of another class. It won't take too much time. @MehulJoisar

Comment: Yeah man, I understand the problem is of using java.* or javax.* .and if I move the classes to different package,it will still have errors because the methods are `package private` .I have tried something similar before posting question over here.I have used bava.* or bavax.* instead of java.* or javax.*  respectively.and TimSort is just one example,I have lots of classes for same issue.